# how to run MySQL sub queries to count the records.

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have three tables in hierarchical order let tables are

```
GroupA(id,and some other field) 
GroupB(id,groupA_id,some fields)
GroupC(id,groupB_id,some fields)
```

let GroupA have A1 which have GroupB as B1,B2,B3, and each GroupB have some GroupC in each.
Now i want to get this information in single query.

```
GroupA   |   Total_GroupB    |    Total_GroupC
  A1     |         4         |          10
  A2     |         6         |          12
```

I try some sub queries but all give some kind of error because my logic is not correct. 
if it is possible then how to do it. I can solve it with multiple queries but i want a single. 
My be it is partially duplicate of some SO questions.

Comment: Instead of telling us about the data, why not just give us the data?

Comment: @Strawberry because tables have many fields so better for me to only put problme here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand by your question, you need something like below

```
SELECT a.id, count(distinct b.id) Total_GroupB, count(distinct c.id) Total_GroupC from GroupA a 
LEFT JOIN GroupB b ON a.id=b.groupa_id 
LEFT JOIN Groupc c ON b.id=c.groupb_id 
GROUP BY a.id
```

Comment: +1 Not a subquery-based answer, but a better approach than using sub-queries.